# jQuery class selection Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

```
<div id="entry{{$allpdt->id}}" class="entry value">
    <span>{{$value}}</span>
</div>
```

How can I call this `div` ID using jQuery?

I am using Laravel 5.4.

```
 $(document).ready(function (e) {
     var ids = $('#ids').val();
     $(document).on('click','#entry+ids', function(){
     });
});
```

I Tried this but it won't work.

Comment: `How can get the id?` which id you are talking about?

Comment: The templating code is of no use, as jQuery cannot see it, and we have no idea what it will render as.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either use an existing class or attach a static class just for the purpose of selecting these elements.

HTML:

```
<div id="entry{{$allpdt->id}}" class="entry value myjQuerySelectorClass">...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.myjQuerySelectorClass').on('click', function(){
    var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

I used an on-click case but you can apply it to your specific situation.